# How to add compile options to CMake FetchContent dependency using target interface

Tags: c++, cmake, fetchcontent

I have a dependency included using CMake's `FetchContent` that needs to be built using some build flag (`cmake -DFLAG=ON`).

This question is also asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708076/how-to-add-compile-options-to-a-cmake-fetchcontent-dependency) and the provided answer seems to be to set a variable on the current scope using `set`. For instance `set(FLAG ON)`.

My question: **Is there a way to achieve the same, without polluting the scope?**

I have tried using `set_target_properties` or `target_compile_options` without success. If I  call these after `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` they have no effect and if I call them before then the target does not exists and it throws an error.

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    Dependency
    GIT_REPOSITORY ...
    GIT_TAG ...
)

set(FLAG ON) # This works, but pollutes the scope. I only want this flag to take effect on "Dependency"

# set_target_properties(Dependency PROPERTIES FLAG ON) # This won't work (error)
# target_compile_options(Dependency PUBLIC -DFLAG=ON) # This won't work either (error)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Dependency)

# set_target_properties(Dependency PROPERTIES FLAG ON) # This has no effect
# target_compile_options(Dependency PUBLIC -DFLAG=ON) # This has no effect
```

Comment: Just `set()` the variable before `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` call and `unset()` it after the call.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this should be an answer or a comment, but you could use the following pattern to not pollute scope:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_OLD "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

# Add other flags here.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-restrict")

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gflags)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_OLD}")
```