# Disable compiler warnings when using FetchContent with CMake

Tags: cmake, googletest, raylib

I'm trying to add a library to my CMake project, but I don't want the compiler to give me warning for this project so that I can enable `-werror`.

For this I tried using the `SYSTEM` flag in `FetchContent`, with no success :

```
FetchContent_Declare(
        raylib
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/raysan5/raylib.git
        GIT_TAG 4.2.0
        SYSTEM
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(raylib)
```

This is the case for raylib and Google Test. Is there something to be done the the library side ? Or can I do something about it ?

Comment: If you can't control/configure this using raylib CMake options, why not just try disabling the warnings on the `raylib` target? `target_compile_options(raylib PRIVATE <list of disabled warnings here>)`

Comment: It could work, but then I would need to add them for every compiler and every dependency. It's not ideal but I guess I could do that for now.

Comment: CMake has no cross-platform notion about compiler options which enable/disable compiler warnings. The most CMake can is to add some include directories as SYSTEM ones, so a compiler won't emit some warnings for *headers* placed in that directory. But this cannot suppress warnings in the *source* files. So you need to explicitly set/unset compiler options which affects the warnings. See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708076/how-to-add-compile-options-to-a-cmake-fetchcontent-dependency) about how to do that in case of FetchContent.